# Drawing contour lines with exact distance?

Tags: arcgis-desktop

I am trying to draw contours with exact distances around my samples (points).

Comment: By "contour line" do you perhaps mean "buffer"?

Comment: @ whuber, I do not know and not sure because all I was trying to draw those contours with exact distance intervals.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the buffer tool (Analysis tools > Proximity) to create equidistant buffers around points. Setting the Dissolve Type to ALL will dissolve the individual buffers into one continuous line feature. Run the tool multiple times to create buffers for each distance you need. If you need buffers around only a subset of all the points, I recommend selecting those points (Select by Attribute) and exporting them to a new feature class before running the buffer.

This method will create "contours" but they will look more bumpy than what you've attempted to do above, however the lines will be equidistant from the input points. Also, the output will have negative space. For example, the black point at the topological bottom of the map will have an isolated buffer around it, the "contour" will not connect to the other black points. However to create a continuous surface as you have done above you must violate the equidistant rule. If a continuous surface is what you need, it may be necessary to employ some method of surface interpolation.

Comment: thank you for your reply! You answered like I was a professional GIS user:) so I followed your advice and found that Analysis tool>Proximity>Buffer and now got stuck because I do not know how to perform rest of them. Could you please describe the procedure in more details gradually, if possible? Your help will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: This help page will provide information regarding the buffer tool: [Buffer Tool](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//000800000019000000). I would recommend playing around with the linear distance parameter and dissolve type to see if any of the outputs will work for you. Surface interpolation may not be suited for this analysis or prove too difficult, but here is a page on it just in case: [Interpolation](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//009z0000006w000000)